# replace spaces with &nbsp; from a recordset

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

How can I change "spaces" on records being returned by a recordset?

For example, I have this code that will return a value of "John Doe":

```
<td width="30%"><%=rsTmp("Name")%></font></td>
```

What I would like to do is to change the space between the words into:

```
&nbsp;
```

so that when my page got congested the name "John Doe" will still be in a straight line, and will not be separated?

Comment: adding `style="white-space: nowrap;"` to your td would also stop the Name from being split onto seperate lines.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved it!
I used replace function like this.

```
<% Replace(rsTmp("Name")," ","&nbsp;")%>
```

Comment: This will generate syntax error. Sure you copied your exact code?

Answer (score 3):

In Classic ASP you will need to code the following:

```
<%= Replace(rsTmp("Name")," ","&nbsp;") %>
```

Which is the same as

```
<%
    Response.Write ( Replace(rsTmp("Name")," ","&nbsp;") )
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I would suggest using `replace(rsTmp("Name"), " ", "&#160;")`

In HTML5 the ASCII code `&nbsp;` are replaced with `&#160;`. You might as well do this from this day and onwards ;)