# Using replace string in ASP

Tags: javascript, regex, asp-classic, replace

I have a working function in JS

```
function countWords(s){
    s = s.replace(/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi,""); //modified trim function
    s = s.replace(/[ ]{2,}/gi," ");
    s = s.replace(/\n /,"\n");
    return s.split(' ').length;
}
```

The problem is when i change to ASP, it seems not working:

```
   Sub formatText(a)
        a = Replace("/(^\s*)|(\s*$)/gi",a,"")
        a = Replace("/[ ]{2,}/gi",a,"")
        a = Replace("/\n /",a,"\n")
        return a
    End Sub
```

It return nothing from the function, how to fix the problem? thanks

Changed to

```
'regEx initialization
Dim regEx
set regEx = New RegExp  'Creates a regexp object
regEx.IgnoreCase = True 'Set case sensitivity
regEx.Global = True     'Global applicability

'trim input text
Sub formatText(a)
    a = Replace("(^\s*)|(\s*$)",a,"")
    a = Replace("[ ]{2,}",a,"")
    regEx.IgnoreCase = False 'Set case sensitivity
    regEx.Global = False     'Global applicability
    a = Replace("\n ",a,"\n")
    return a
End Sub
```

still no luck please help..

Comment: The `/` at the beginning and end of your regexes is _JavaScript_ regex literal syntax, not part of the actual regex expressions. You don't want it in your ASP version, though I don't know how to set the `g` and `i` flags or their equivalent in VB.

Comment: May be your problem will resolve from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219317/replace-spaces-with-nbsp-from-a-recordset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use a regex object, like so:

```
'regEx initialization
Dim regEx
set regEx = New RegExp  'Creates a regexp object
regEx.IgnoreCase = True 'Set case sensitivity
regEx.Global = True     'Global applicability

regEx.Pattern = "<[^>]*>" 'Remove all HTML
strTextToStrip = regEx.Replace(strTextToStrip, " ")
```

Also remove the `/` from around the pattern.

**UPDATED**

```
'trim input text
Function formatText(a)
    Dim regEx
    set regEx = New RegExp  'Creates a regexp object
    regEx.IgnoreCase = True 'Set case sensitivity
    regEx.Global = True     'Global applicability

    regEx.Pattern = "(^\s*)|(\s*$)"
    a = regEx.Replace(a, "")

    regEx.Pattern = "[ ]{2,}"
    a = regEx.Replace(a, "")

    formatText = a
End Function
```

Comment: is using count as -1 can do the same thing?
Replace(expression, find, replacewith[, start[, count[, compare]]])

Comment: I don't believe so no, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9z80300(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: sorry but would you mind have a look at my changed version, why it still return nothing?